# httpWebRequest - get error content

Tags: wcf, rest, error-handling

I throw an error in my REST service like:

```
throw new WebFaultException<String>("bla bla bla",
   HttpStatusCode.HttpVersionNotSupported);
```

but when I try to get the error content in

```
var r = (HttpWebResponse)(request.GetResponse());
if (r.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {...
```

The problem is that GetResponse() throws a WebException error. And it is impossible for me to get the "bla bla bla" text. How can I get this text? The web exception contains the status code HttpVersionNotSupported but no property that contains the text "bla bla bla". Where is the data I send as first parameter of WebFaultException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method to access the contents of the response. The sample code in the link should you show how to read and clean up the stream.

Comment: request.GetResponse throws webException Exception. Thus I can not access object r from my code

Comment: Hmmm, I missed that in your question somehow. What type is the `request` variable?